# Unable to install matplotlib 3.0.2

Tags: cmd, pip, installation, python-3.7

I have python3.7.2 on my computer.
This is where it is in my computer --> `C:\Program Files\Python37`
I have tried to open up cmd on my computer and tried to type in `cd Python37` but it doesn't find the python. If it opened up the next step for me would be to type in: `pip install matplotlib==3.0.2`

What should I type in cmd in order to find Python?

Comment: Probably could if understood more of these things :/ I mean this is a python for dummies kind of course im attending, and i need numpy to practice with. What should i type in to my cmd in order to find the python and to install the pip version 3.0.2. We have instructions to type in "cd Python37" if we have it on C:// just like I have but the cmd says that it cant find

Answer (score 0):

If you have python installed on your computer you should first add `C:\Program Files\Python37` to `PATH` environment variable.

You can refer [this link](https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/) for the same.

After that you can check your `script` folder inside `C:\Program Files\Python37` if it has `pip/pip3` on it.

Now you can go to `cd C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts` using command prompt.
Run `pip3 install matplotlib` to install matplotlib.

Hope this helps.